# How do I view Cordova log messages from my connected Android device?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

After running `cordova run android` how can I see the Cordova log in my terminal window?

Answer (score 2):

```
adb logcat
```

will show all the messages from the device. You can filter this to just show the messages from Cordova with

```
adb logcat CordovaLog:V  *:S
```

This sets the level for Cordova to Verbose, and everything else to Silent

Answer (score 0):

I use adb logcat and write to a file

`adb logcat | find "Web Console" > c:\dev\adb.log`

And watch using Baretail (or other tail), to highlight relevant stuff.